# Comunicar un AlertDialog (DialogFragment) con un Fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, alertdialog, navigation

Tengo una `base de datos` y para añadir datos lo hago con un `AlertDialog` ([`Creating a Custom Layout`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=en#CustomLayout)). El `AlertDialog` tiene dos `TextEdit` y los dos botones de aceptar y cancelar. Cuando se rellenan los dos `TextEdit` y das al botón de aceptar se añaden a la base de datos.

Luego tengo un `Fragment` con dos botones:

1. Uno para mostrar el `AlertDialog` y el otro está desactivado.
2. El botón desactivado se activa cuando en la base de datos tenga alguna fila de datos. El `AlertDialog` se llama `AddAccountDialog` y el `Fragment` `IniFragment`.

Mi principal objetivo es activar un método del `IniFragment` después de dar al botón de aceptar del `AddAccountDialog`.

Estoy usando el [`NAVIGATION COMPONENT`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#create-nav-graph).

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_mainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`dialog_add_account.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_addAccountDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_accountName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nombre de la cuenta"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Cantidad"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**COMUNICARSE ENTRE DESTINOS USANDO [`SAFE ARGS`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args)**

Parto de que en el `nav_graph.xml` se puede colocar el `AlertDialog` ([`Create a destination from a DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#create-dialog)).

Y como se trata de un destino se pueden pasar argumentos. Lo que pensé fue que puede pasar un `boolean arg` para mandar al `IniFragment` que se ha actualizado la base de datos:

`nav_graph.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/iniFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/iniFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mayu.IniFragment"
        android:label="fragment_ini"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ini" >
        <argument
            android:name="updateBool"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_iniFragment_to_addAccountDialog"
            app:destination="@id/addAccountDialog" />
    </fragment>
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/addAccountDialog"
        android:name="com.example.mayu.AddAccountDialog"
        android:label="dialog_add_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/dialog_add_account" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addAccountDialog_to_iniFragment"
            app:destination="@+id/iniFragment" />
    </dialog>
</navigation>
```

No hay problema cuando le doy al botón del `IniFragment` para que aparezca el `AlertDialog`:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_iniFragment_to_addAccountDialog);
```

El problema es cuando le doy al botón de aceptar, salta el siguiente error:

`AddAccountDialog.java`

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_account, null);

    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Añadir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            //CÓDIGO PARA AÑADIR LOS DATOS DE LOS TEXTEDIT A LA BASE DE DATOS

            // enviar datos al otro fragment
            AddAccountDialogDirections.ActionAddAccountDialogToIniFragment action = AddAccountDialogDirections.actionAddAccountDialogToIniFragment();
            action.setUpdateBool(true);
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            AddAccountDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{31aab9a V.E...... ........ 0,0-936,336 #7f080089 app:id/layout_addAccountDialog} does not have a NavController set
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:84)
```

Si alguien tiene una mejor idea para activar el método del `Fragment` después de dar al botón de aceptar del `DialogFragment` también me vale.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta línea:

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(AddAccountDialog.this).navigate(action);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, acostumbra agregar lo que realiza el código que señalas y como ayudaría a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [answer], saludos..